# React-Native — How can I trigger the iOS/Android native screen reader from a function?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, accessibility, native

Is it possible to trigger the native iOS/Android screen readers from a React-Native function? If so, how can I achieve that? Any resources are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See the React Native [AccessibilityInfo API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibilityinfo.html).

Comment: Emperor, thank you for your reply. I am aware of the API, but it is still unclear to me how to trigger the native screen reader event. I found something in another post that uses announceForAccessibility(). I will try it.

Comment: @DiegoOriani did you have any luck with this, or did you have to implement another TTS solution?

Comment: @CAJE unfortunately I had no luck with this.

Comment: @DiegoOriani I appreciate your answer :) We used `expo-speech` in the end